# Query para sumar no me da el resultado

Tags: mysql, sql, php7

Estoy intentando sumar las cantidades de una columna, tengo este query, pero al mostrarlo en Web no me arroja el resultado.

```html
<td>
<?php 
  $query = mysqli_query ("SELECT SUM(importe_total) FROM consumobar"); 
  $result =  mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query); 
  echo "<p>$result</p>"; 
?>
</td>
```

Comment: mysqli_query() recibe dos parámetros, el primero es la conexión a la base de datos el segundo es la consulta, en tu caso solo estás enviando un parámetro

Comment: Este es el que usaba anteriormente y me corria sin problemas, estoy migrando  a php7 y el código que postie es el que use y no me corre 
<tbody>
 <td><?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(importe_total) FROM consumocafeteria"); $resultado = mysql_result($query, 0); echo "<p>$resultado</p>"; ?></td>                                                                <td><?php $totalpago= $resultado-300; echo "<p>$totalpago</p>"; ?></td>
</tbody>

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar `mysqli_query` entregando dos parámetros:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

Por lo demás $result es un array:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
       echo $row["Name"];
    }
```

Puedes usar `var_dump` para visualizar la estructura del array que te arroja.

Comment: Hola Christopher, tu respuesta más que una respuesta parece un comentario, cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás tener el privilegio de comentar en todas partes para hacer comentarios como estos, **es importante que leas [answer]** y te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla.